# Select by attributes to create feature classes

Tags: arcpy, query, feature-layer, loop

I am using OSM point data and am trying to pull out schools, hospitals and place of worship. I have created my feature layer and am using a "for loop" to make from each amenity its own shapefile.

What I currently have will create the 3 shapefiles all with hospitals populating every shapefile. Do I have to create a new query for each amenity and then make a new feature layer from that?

amenities = ['school','hospital','place_of_worship']

[image]

Comment: Please always include code as text rather than pictures so that it is available to future searches and to copy/paste for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly how your data looks, you could make this change to your code and have it dynamically change the query:

```
pointquery = '"amenity" = "{0}"'.format(amenity)
```

This will populate the query from your amenities list.